# Detecting when an option has been selected

Tags: javascript, html

This looks quite simple but I didn't find an answer to this.

I have a basic `<select>` tag that contains many basic `<option>` tags. So far, so good. I've started my React component by adding a listener `onChange` on the select tag, which works fine.

But this does not really address my concern. `onChange` is triggered only if the option's value is not the same than the select's value. I want my function to be triggered as soon as any option is selected, even if the value of the `<select>` does not change, I want to know that the user selected something and retriggers a whole processing. So `onChange` is probably not what I want to use but I didn't find out what to use.

Here is a sample of code:

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", e => console.log(e.target.value));
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Bip</option>
  <option>Bop</option>
</select>
```

Is this possible with a basic select tag and some options inside? I'd like to avoid implementing a component just for that and keep being standard as much as I can.

Thank you guys!

**UPDATE**

Just found out that this post was a duplicate and the trick is to check the click event for its property `detail`!

Comment: Please always include the relevant code and your attempt at a solution to your problem in your question. We do expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've added a snippet, I honestly thought text was enough as it is a really simple case.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the general convention is, we want to do something when the user selects something other than the selected one because the processing for the existing value is already done.

But if you still want to do what you have mentioned, you can simply add a `onClick` handler to the `<select>` tag. Now what that will do is fire the event every time user clicks on any of the options.

Check out the following

```js
const handleChange = (obj) => {
    alert(`User changed value to ${obj.value}`);
};

const handleClick = (obj) => {
    alert(`User clicked on ${obj.value}`);
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
section select {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <select onchange="handleChange(this)" onclick="handleClick(this)">
        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
        <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

Comment: Please do not link to your code as links can die over time and then your answer becomes meaningless. Instead, include your code as a Stack Snippet (the `{}` button when you are composing your answer), which will execute right here.

Comment: @mrJ The issue with `onclick` is that it is triggered not only when the user selects an option, but also when the user expand the dropdown, and I don't want to catch this event. Maybe there is some way to determine whether the <select> is expanded or not, but I'm not aware of it.